# CPU Still Powercycles after swapping PSU > Reset BIOS > SSD won't boot but LIVE USB does

Tags: boot, ssd, bios, power-supply

Running an Asus Z87-A and a Samsung 840 SSD (I disconnected the GPU and extraneous HDD).

A few weeks ago I got a warning that the Mobo had detected surges (Computer is plugged into a APC UPS). I come in today and the CPU powercycles with the CPU LED on. After powering everything down, and resetting the BIOS, I'm able to boot into BIOS, but when I try to boot into OS (Ubuntu 14.04) I just return to the BIOS.

I'm able to boot onto a live USB, and the SMART tools didn't detect anything wrong on the SSD.

**UPDATE**

I swapped PSUs and still get powercycling, sometimes the power-cycling stops by itself and computer will POST and then tell me the mobo detected a surge. Is my motherboard fried in some way?

Comment: Is the installation on the SSD a UEFI installation? Or have you been using CSM/legacy boot? It could be the UEFI boot (NVRAM) entry got erased somehow. Would be good if you can boot the live USB in UEFI mode and run `efibootmgr` to check.

Comment: I have to `chroot` into the boot drive before running `efibootmgr` yeah?
I'm going to try swapping out the PSU first. It seems every new day I have to reset the BIOS in order to get to POST so clearly something else is up.

Comment: No, `efibootmgr` simply check the your NVRAM (`/sys/firmware/efi/efivars`), and you don't need to chroot for that.

Comment: So I swapped in a new PSU, ran `efibootmgr` and deleted the old Ubuntu entries and created a new one. When I tried to boot into Ubuntu it would just take me from the EZ EFI screen to the advanced EFI screen. I have three extra drives in a software RAID, connected them all. Next time I power on the computer goes through 2 powercycles before telling me the mobo detected power supply surges during the previous power on.

Comment: `...created a new one` Well created how? What's the full and exact command you ran? `When I tried to boot into Ubuntu` So you mean you can at least see the entry on your UEFI boot menu? `another BIOS screen` What does that mean? It led you to UEFI settings?

Comment: I used the command `efibootmgr -c Ubuntu` with the boot SSD as the only drive connected. Also edited my comment above regarding screens.

Comment: I don't think only specifying `-c Ubuntu` is gonna work. You'll need to specify the disk, partition and path of the EFI binary. For example, if `sda1` is your EFI System Partition (ESP), then you should run something like`efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -l /EFI/grub/grubx64.efi`. Note that this is just an example. Check exactly which partition is your ESP (with `fdisk -l` for example) and check the content of it to determine the path. Leave out the mountpoint of the ESP when specify the path and prefix it with a `/`. FWIW `efibootmgr -v` tells you what exactly the entry is pointing to.

Comment: Also, if you want to have Secure Boot enabled, you may not want the UEFI to load grub directly but maybe some preloader like shim. Or, just make sure Secure Boot is disabled.

Comment: My SSD doesn't have an `ef00` partition, just a FAT32 one, a swap, and one labelled BIOS Boot. Should I be specifying the BIOS boot partition?

Comment: What's inside the FAT32 partition? A BIOS Boot partition? So you have actually been using grub `i386-pc` and CSM/legacy boot instead of grub `x86_64-efi` and UEFI boot? What's inside `/boot/grub` on the SSD?

Comment: My bad, the FAT32 is actually Ext4, which contains the OS.

Comment: So you have not been doing UEFI boot at all. Have you (re-)enabled legacy boot / CSM in UEFI settings in that case? Can you see the SSD on the boot menu (with all "Ubuntu entries" deleted with `efibootmgr`)?

Comment: Uncertain, considering there were previously UEFI records... Anyways. If I enable legacy/CSM, when booting on the SSD it justs hangs with a flashing underscore `_`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/37079/discussion-between-tom-yan-and-raphael).

Answer (score 0):

Change the BIOS from UEFI to Legacy mode (or reverse).   If that fails, try changing the SATA emulation (AHCI vs Legacy).

Comment: Why was this downvoted ?

Comment: I didn't down vote. But have an up vote. I'll try all UEFI combinations and see if that works

Comment: @davidgo For its lack of rationality, especially the IDE mode part.

Answer (score 0):

You should check your wall wiring. As I understand it, smaller consumer UPS systems are switching: there is a measurable time between your power company's power sag and the UPS power becoming available. So unless your UPS is an "online type" (expensive), this is a *potential* source.

PC power spec has something like a 20ms hold-up time before "all the juice drains out." I'd expect an APC UPS to have a quicker switch-over time, but it is plausible something isn't playing nice. Note that switching can cause transient surges.

It may be that your computer system is detecting the problem during the switch-over. I have had whole-house brownouts where only one out of three computers in the same room responded in any noticeable way.

Additionally, surge protective devices have a life expectancy. Either lots of small events or fewer large events. So it is plausible that you are having lots of small events and your device is still passing power but not actually offering surge protection. Surge protectors should be an order of magnitude faster than switch-over.

Comment: So I did try plugging the computer directly into the wall with similar issues. But I will try a different outlet.

Comment: So I moved to a different outlet and still get the CPU powercycling/motherboard shutting down the computer with and without UPS. I should note that this computer had been operating in this space for 4 months before these troubles started. Besides moving the computer to a different office. do you know how I could determine if the problem is with the wiring vs. motherboard?